# Get Size Of File From Commandline Input In C

Tags: c, file, command-line, size

I'm trying to get the size of a file from the commandline in C using argv. I'm not too familiar with file i/o in C, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should try Googling things like "C argv" or "C argv parsing". Results such as these appear: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/

Comment: `man stat` or search MSDN for `GetFileSizeEx`.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the size of a file **from the commandline**?"

Answer (score 3):

You've not stated the platform, but your C program is given an argument list when it is started, and the file names are strings.  The POSIX function you'd probably use is [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html); it takes a pointer to a `struct stat` and will put the file's size into the `st_size` member of the structure.

The answer may be different on Windows; the POSIX subsystem will provide a `stat()` workalike (probably named `_stat()`), but there'll also be a native interface.